# The hover style in css is not working for my button

Tags: html, css

I have a button in my nav bar but i the hover style to edit the button doesn't work. When the cursor hovers over the button i would like the color of the text and the background to change.

```css
.inlineButton {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: block;
  margin: 1rem auto;
  width: 90%;
  height: 2rem;
  padding: 0.2rem;
  background-color: #85144b;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.inlineButton:hover {
  color: #000000;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<button type='newHead' id='newHead' class='inlineButton'>Header</button>
```

Comment: When pasting the ".inlineButton:hover" part of the css, I am getting a symbol of the color before the texts. If this is happening to you as well, delete the symbol and it will work fine.

Comment: It is working fine. Please check if there is any special character added in your class name, or just copy paste it from the HTML button.

Comment: `type='newHead'` is not a valid button type.

Comment: This is working version after approve the edit. So still you looking solution?

Comment: As the code is already working, so it should be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code:

```
 .inlineButton:hover {
      color: #000000;
      background-color: #FFFFFF;
      -webkit-appearance: none;
    }
```

Comment: It's not necessary to remove the default appearance in webkit to be able to set color and background-color of a button.

Answer (score -1):

Two changes here:

a.  button type you mentioned not valid,

b. I added space between CSS property and their values.

```html
<head>
  <title>Editor</title>
  <style>
  .inlineButton{
     box-sizing: border-box;
     display: block;
     margin: 1rem auto;
     width: 90%;
     height: 2rem;
     padding: 0.2rem;
     background-color: #85144b;
     font-weight:300;
     color:#FFFFFF;
     text-align:center;
     transition: all 0.2s;
     cursor: pointer;
  }

 .inlineButton:hover {
     color: #000000;
     background-color: #ffffff;
  }
  </style>

</head>

<body>
<div id="inputArea">
  <div id="leftNav">
     <button type='button' id='newHead' 
      class='inlineButton'>Header</button>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How does this address OP's question?

Comment: @connexo then what you got from Question, can you little bit explain dear?

Comment: @connexo when first time posted the question it was not working as expected that's why I provided a solution what is working perfectly. What's my wrong there?